# How to add background color using css pseudo attribute

Tags: css, reactjs

Am trying to achieve the result attached in the screenshot. But am not able to achieve the result. Should not introduce any new DOM element to achieve the desired output.

Open the demo link and select the date range, start date and end date selections are not as expected.

[demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-day-picker-examplesselected-range-g4hjo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with your CSS and was able to achieve what you are looking for.

Maybe try something like the following:

```
.DayPicker-Day--start {
    color: #fff !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 50% !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50% !important;
}

.DayPicker-Day--end {
    color: #fff !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 50% !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50% !important;
}

.DayPicker-Day--selected {
    background-color: #C4C4C4 !important;
    color: #1C1C1C;
    z-index: 1;
}

.DayPicker-Day--selected::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1C1C1C !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I think z-index values may have been what was causing trouble.

[Here's a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UvXc.jpg) to screenshots of my inspector, in case that helps. I had #ccc as a placeholder but forgot to change it, so just change that to the gray that you actually want for your background.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to get the results you asked for after:

- changing the `z-index: -1`
- splitting the selector to set `left: 0` for `--end`
- setting the `width: 50%;` & `height: 100%`

The following is what I split the `.Selectable .DayPicker-Day--start:after, .Selectable .DayPicker-Day--end:after` selector into:

```css
.Selectable .DayPicker-Day--start:after{
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f0f8ff!important;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: -1;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
  }
  
  .Selectable .DayPicker-Day--end:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f0f8ff!important;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Here's the result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Yes, z-index was causing the problem. Thank you for the solution